# Solution for listview Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Here is my `Lisview` Adapter code :

```
public class KategoriaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Kategoria> {
```

The problem is that the `Listview` is totally empty. The list which is in constructor of Adapter has correct values. I guess that the problem is in Adapter. I'm looking for any clues. I just added getItem method and still nothing.

Comment: Can we see more code? :)

Comment: could  post getItem method ?

Comment: I just add it and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't implemented `getItem()` method.

```
@Override
public Object getItem (int position) {
    return this.items.get(position);
}
```